# How to prevent Samsung Tab 10.1 from turning display on by itself?

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, 3.2-honeycomb

I just bought this Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 3.2 and while I love it, one thing drives me nuts - every time I turn the screen off using power button, the screen comes back on in a minute or so. I went through all display settings and haven't found anything relevant.

Any ideas how to stop that madness?

Comment: If the screen automatically switches on without the user having intiated this, it looks to me like some app requested a specific WakeLock (`SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`, or `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, see [PowerManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)). Please check if [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575) might help you.

Comment: It looks like ambient display is the cause of this have you checked related settings