# How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?

Tags: battery-life, wakelock

I guess most of you at least have *heard* about [WakeLocks](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Wakelocks). Many of you will have *experienced* them already -- wether knowingly or not. Some may know how to deal with them in general -- but only few know how to deal with the "more complicated candidates".

For those who don't know, though above link leads to an explanation, a short summary: Apps may request a `WAKE_LOCK` to keep a device component from "sleeping", so they can perform a task even when the display is turned off. This is very useful in most cases (e.g. keeping the screen on while navigating, keeping WiFi active to stream music) -- but used in the wrong way, it causes your battery to be drained within short term (up to 25% per hour).

Most times it is easy to identify the source (usually a bad behaving app) -- I will show this in an answer below, as it might prove helpful to many users. But what to do if the app which requested the WakeLock exits without releasing it? The Android system [will not take care of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780280/how-can-i-see-which-wakelocks-are-active). Sure, a reboot would solve the issue -- but it is not always an (desired) option.

So, from a users perspective (I'm not asking about development solutions, but how a user can handle things):

**What can be done **by the user** to solve the issue and avoid further battery drain?**

I prefer answers *not* involving root (so all users can benefit from it). However, "rooted solutions" are fully valid and welcome as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that this was only true if you created the wakelock the "wrong" way, by using `/sys/power/wake_lock`, but that if you did it the "right" way using PowerManager and PowerManager.WakeLock, the service would both hold the real wakelock and release it even if your process was killed...

Comment: According to the information I linked, that's obviously not the case. Somebody reports there having checked the kernel sources, and did not find any hint to that. Hint for developers: seems like "partial wakelocks" can be requested *timed*, so they'd expire automatically when the timer's up and the wakelock aquire was not refreshed. That must be the "safe way" you refer to.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### How can I tell I'm affected?

This is probably the first question to those not familiar with this topic. With Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and above, you've got a service aboard helping you to figure out: battery statistics. Though manufacturers tend to place it at different points, it's mostly found in *Settings → About the phone → Battery* or similar, and shows a list of the apps having used most of your battery. On top of that is a small graph. Tap that, and it brings you to a screen similar to this one:

[image: battery stats]
<sup>Screenshot of battery statistics on Android 2.3</sup>

I chose a screenshot from one of my devices which illustrates the issue. Looking at the lower two blue bars ("Aktiv" = Device was kept awake (active), "Bildschirm an" = "Screen on"), the right-most blue bar on "Aktiv" indicates a WakeLock: Device was kept busy despite the fact the screen was turned off. So by this we can be pretty sure we've got a WakeLock -- but we cannot tell who caused it.

If your device does not offer this screen (or the bars at the bottom: I just discovered e.g. the *LG Optimus 4X* running Android 4.0.3 has cut these bars off), you can find them e.g. using [GSam Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm):

[image: GSam Battery Monitor]
<sup>Similar information from [GSam Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) -- here the mentioned "blue bars" are yellow/orange</sup>

### What caused the WakeLock?

Unfortunately, this question cannot be answered using pre-installed apps (except for, maybe, some Custom ROMs). But there are tools available that can. The best known candidate for this is [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats), and shows us the cause in its *partial wakelocks* section:

[image: BetterBatteryStats] [image: BetterBatteryStats2]
<sup>Screenshots from BetterBatteryStats</sup>

In the first example<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsfQ3.jpg)</sup> (taken from the app's playstore page), the event causing most of the WakeLocks was a desired one: We don't want the playback stopped while listening to music. So the second example<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buI7o.jpg)</sup> (taken from a real case on one of my devices) might prove better: the topmost 3 events are caused by the very same app, which needed the WakeLock to keep the IMAP push service active.

For an alternative to *BetterBatteryStats*, check out the [Wakelock Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) app mentioned in [UzumApps' answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41061/16575) -- which seems easier to handle especially for non-techies:

[image: Wakelock Detector: App details] [image: Wakelock Detector: Select processes]
<sup>Wakelock Detector -- Click image to enlarge. (Source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector))</sup>

### What can be done?

If the case is as clear as in the second example in the previous section, the action is quite obvious -- at least in my case: I don't need to be informed *immediately* when a mail arrives; a delay of 30min is absolutely acceptable. So I went into the mail app, disabled [IMAP Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-IMAP) (see also: [Push Email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_email)), and instead switched to a 30min poll interval. WakeLocks did not entirely disappear, but dropped markably -- battery life improved noticably.

Then there's the case mentioned in the question itself: A bad behaving app not releasing its WakeLock. Confront the dev with your findings and ask for a fix. If he delivers: problem solved. If not: There's almost always an alternative app available.

### What if it is the Android System itself?

Yeah, sometimes it looks like just that: 98% or more consumed by some Android service. Oh, if it's 98%, in most cases the candidate is named *LocationManagerService*. Bad guy spying at us? Not necessarily. In this special case, the listed "bad guy" is not even guilty -- at least not directly. Here it is another app requesting the current location too frequently. There's an excellent article on Setera.org about this: [Pinpointing Android LocationManagerService battery drain](http://www.setera.org/2012/09/10/pinpointing-android-locationmanagerservice-battery-drain/). To give an abstract: It uses Android's `dumpsys` feature (requires root!) to dump a system state, and lets you investigate the listeners established for the LocationManagerService. A closer look at their configuration shows which are constantly "hammering" it for location info (some do so permanently, i.e. without a break). As the app's ID is listed along, and at another place in the dump even together with the apps technical name, you can still identify it and take appropriate actions.

### And what about UFOs?

Unfortunately, there are such: Apps which registered a WakeLock -- and then exited without releasing it. What's left are *Unused F***ing Obsoletes* -- WakeLocks held for no use. So no way to simply bring the app to foreground and re-configure, or making it release its WakeLocks.

Here the only solution known to me is a reboot -- and I would like to have a better solution. Of course, if you know the guilty app, the steps concerning it are the same as above: inform the dev, get a fix -- or replace the app. But about getting rid of the *current* WakeLock? Maybe somebody else can provide a better alternative to the reboot?

### Are there some recommended further readings?

Sure. One for now, I may add more later:

- [[GUIDE] Wakelocks Definition and how to prevent them](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2171461) (XDA Developers, March 2013)

Comment: Better education to developers to say... "Release wakelocks when you are done with them and clean up after yourself"?

Comment: Sure -- but see my question: I'm explicitly **NOT** asking about the developer side, but *from a users perspective*. Maybe I need to make that more obvious ;)

Comment: If I have time this weekend, I will poke around under the hood to see if there's a mechanism to get the kernel to boot out orphaned wakelocks.... ;)

Comment: Please do! And report your findings! I just had that described issue with the "orphaned" WakeLocks. Poking around for an hour, I didn't get further than seeing it was the *LocationManagerService*. Registered for updates all 0sec (sic!) was the *Android Settings* (=:-0). I exited it, stopped it, killed it at the command line... no way to get rid of the locks. WTF did *Settings* do there? A reboot solved it, of course -- but is this a WindowsPhone we have to reboot twice a day?

Answer (score 6):

In short, this is a very good question but am afraid, it warrants more than just making the end-user aware!

Redesign the kernel to eliminate wake-locks and use a more thorough efficient way of managing the principle better thereby prolonging battery life.

Unfortunately, it has been accepted as a de-facto solution to enable "power management" despite it is not exactly efficient either! There was an extensive discussion about wakelocks (with Gregh Kroah Hartman - the Linux guru for drivers development - am googling for the exact linky), other sites such as [LWN.net](http://lwn.net/Articles/479841/) and another article explained on the same site [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/416690/). This was the article Gregh Kroah Hartman referred to this [blog](http://swik.net/opensuse/Planet+SuSE/Greg+Kroah-Hartman%3a+Greg+Kroah-Hartman%3a+Android+kernel+wakelock+solution/fax8v), in which he appears to agree with the alternative solution proposed by *Rafael J. Wysocki* have documented a lot about the potential alternative. *Am not sure if that is actually in place in the more modern kernel v3.x.x.*

Badly designed apps can and often request wakelocks such as keeping the screen on, but in fact, in this scenario for keeping the screen on, there is in fact a more efficient way to do this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Whilst, striving to keep this clear of jargon etc for the end user, really the core of the issue boils down to the kernel code in how the wakelocks are managed.

Here is a brief summary on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1462020) on what is wakelocks for the uninitiated. By using [BetterBatteryStats](https://github.com/asksven/BetterBatteryStats-Knowledge-Base/wiki/_pages), one could see exactly which process is draining the battery, the wiki is hosted on github, and is available on the market [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats).

Comment: Funny you point to the same XDA thread I mentioned. I agree with you that the system should take better care (e.g. by releasing WakeLocks requested by apps which are no longer running). And that developers should take better care in coding (by explicitly releasing them at the appropriate states of the LifeCycle). But that doesn't help us users *know*. I hope my answer gives some insight in what a user can do -- and that one of you "techies" can fill the gap left!

Answer (score 3):

Check out *Wakelock Detector:* [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2179651) / [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector):

Wakelock detector groups the wakelocks of app into one expandable view for better look. And it shows which apps are running. And there are kill uninstall info buttons in expanded view of app.

[image: Wakelock Detector: App details] [image: Wakelock Detector: Select processes]
<sup>Click image to enlarge. (Source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector))</sup>

Disclosure: I am one of responsible developer for this app. Four more friends are with me working on this project as a hobby.

Comment: Thank you! That's a valuable information indeed. Would you mind to add some more details to your answer, e.g. what makes it so special? I would add some screenshots then. Until that's done: Here's the [Playstore link to the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector)...

Comment: Thank you for the details! I merged them into your answer, I hope you don't mind :) Question of understanding: Say an app queries the location using an interval of "0 seconds". This would cause the *LocationService* to wakelock the device. Would *Wake Lock Detector* show the responsible app then as the real cause -- or the *LocationService*, as it's not a part of that apps package?

Comment: The answer for your question is 'no'  because wakelock detector groups wakelocks that belong to the same app packagename. As Location Service belongs to android os, the solution would be checking User permissions of app

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping for an easy solution to the "What if it is the Android System itself?" part. Seems there isn't such a thing -- but if it's possible, it might be a good idea to integrate with WLD :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways that would help **unrooted device** users

1. Seeing that @Uzumapps, one of the developers of the app has posted a [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41061/131553) using [Wakelock Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector&hl=en) (**WLD**), I am surprised that he has not updated about using the app which can also be used **without root called Wakelock Detector Light** ! I discovered this searching for a solution for my new device (unrooted).

This is a recent development and hence posting this for unrooted device users. Tested as working on Moto X Play (Android 6.0.1)

- Download WLD from Play store link above
- Manual for using WLD [here](http://www.slideshare.net/ahikmat1/manual-for-wakelock-detector?from_action=save)
- Instructions for  non rooted devices [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1r3VlhZIZVSufZlAeICJet6QBtyAF7z06_ysl1kUKME4/edit#slide=id.g123bc9f140_169_48). It has all the details but to summarise:

  - Enable USB debugging on device and `adb`
  - Download [Wakelock Unlocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlocker-for-wakelockdete/bgeplmmblegmdackkcemjkpngngocgjp) for Chrome on your laptop (also works on Chromium)
  - Enable it and you are done !
  - [Wakelock Detector Light version does not display stats since Unplugged](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=66471000&highlight=lite#post66471000)

    2. There is another alternative on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2p05zu/til_you_can_easily_get_wakelocks_information/cmtg9ds) which involves running command below in a *loop* as mentioned [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/moto-x-2013/541427-wakelock-detection-without-root.html)

  > adb shell dumpsys power | grep -i partial_wake_lock

**Note:** I couldn't get the second method working, would welcome editing solution in making it work for non savvy guys like me