# Mediaserver is eating my phone's battery?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, 4.2-jelly-bean, media-scanner

I'm using dual boot on my SGS2 with CM10.1 and JellyBam and both running fine but with some issue of **mediaserver** draining my phone's battery like a crazy nut. I have checked on Google and got many threads about this without any proper solution. [This question already exist](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35093/mediaserver-using-excessive-cpu-time-and-battery) on this site but that solution doesn't work for me and rebooting every time is a big pain.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of "Battery Usage" (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I've also deleted all media files on my Sdcard but it still trigger to eat my battery.