# How do I determine which process woke up the screen?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life, screen

The screen woke up at 4am or 5am at night, and had been on ever since.

How can I find out the process that was responsible for screen-wake ups?

The device is Galaxy S III running Android Jellybean 4.1.2.

Thank you

Comment: What device? What android version?

Comment: @t0mm13b i9300 Galaxy S3 4.1.2

Comment: Running facebook, gtalk, gmail or something that was left in the background?

Comment: @t0mm13b yes, fb, gtalkg, gmail are installed

Comment: sign out of any of them?

Comment: no, never do that before sleep

Comment: I've noticed at least once that I plugged my phone into charger (S3 with 4.1.2), and screen was on, but screen just stayed on all night -- just sat there at lock screen. Not sure if it's related to your situation

Comment: As "wake up" in most cases has to do with "wake locks", you might also see [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575) for additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [GSam Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) (formally knows as Bad Ass Battery Monitor)  it will keep track of the number of times and for how long each app keep the device awake.

Open GSAM and go to the App Sucker view (icon on the lower left). Then change the view to Time Held Awake.  To see the number of time an app held the device awake press on the app.

[image: Screenshot of GSam]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In Order to determine, which process causing the WakeLock, you can use [betterBatteryStats](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809) from XDA.

Its proven over periods, the App provides clear list of what are all process causing the wake lock and their count as well.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check "Wakelock Detector" - [WLD at GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) (disclosure: I am the author)

Choose "Full wakelocks" option to see which apps are using screen wakelocks!

Currently running processes are shown in Green color, which makes it easy to recognize the suspicious app.

Here is a screenshot, where the Ad Notification was detected. It was waking up my screen randomly.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: App does not exist