# Is there a way to automatically turn off wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life, automation

I have an LG P990, and I recently upgraded it to ICS. Since that, the charging is much slower and energy consumption is much faster. I could live with it, I charged it at work and at home too.

Yesterday however it went from 85% to empty in one night. 49% of the energy consumption is Wifi according to Battery usage.

I want to know how to periodically turns WiFi on, and after a few minutes off. Every program I was able to find did the first part, but when it found a known network, left it on indefinitely.

In the settings I have "Keep wifi on during sleep" set on "Never", but it does not help.

Comment: András, please note I slightly adjusted your question to avoid it being closed as off topic (*Is there an app for X?*, see our [FAQ]). I also added an answer with some useful points you might want to check out *before* you put an additional app to use :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing so, I'd consider two more things:

### Finding the real cause

High WiFi usage is not caused by WiFi itself (standby), but most likely by another app constantly requesting it to "stay awake". So first check [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575) -- which also deals with this.

### Checking your WiFi standby policy

In *Settings→Wireless & Networks→WiFi*, when pressing the menu button, an item named "Advanced" appears. Tap that to go into the advanced settings and check the *Wifi Standby Policy*. There are 3 options available:

- Always: WiFi stays awake even when the display is turned off. Useful if you're streaming music.
- Only when connected: Only when a power source is connected (i.e. the device is charging) -- as in that case the "battery consumption" usually is not an issue.
- Never: WiFi goes to standby as soon as the display is turned off.

### WiFi managing tools

If this requirement still is present after thoroughly checking above two points, there are multiple options available in this section -- enough to fill at least a small book. First, there are tools like e.g. [JuiceDefender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender) or [GreenPower](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gpo.greenpower), dealing not only with WiFi and mobile networks, but covering a lot more energy saving stuff. Other interesting tools might include [WifiBatt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neniinoo.android) and many others -- just check the related apps on their playstore pages, or use [Mapsaurus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapsaurus.apps) to find similar apps.

Comment: I have tried JuiceDefender earlier today, wifi settings can not be changed in the free version, or it has the most confusing UI I have ever seen.

Comment: As I said in the opening post, _Never_ is set in Wifi Standby Policy. Thanks for the other tip about WakeLocks

Comment: You're welcome. I added the other part although for completeness, so if other "searchers" check they see this is an important part to check. As for *JuiceDefender*: I tried it long time ago, and yes: configuration can be a bit confusing. They have a [feature comparision on their homepage](http://www.juicedefender.com/overview/) (end of the page), just in case you want to check. That page also gives an overview of what you can do with it and how.

Comment: I would not recommend GreenPower. After setting it up the wifi ate much less, but GreenPower itself became the second largest consumer of electrons. Only a slight improvement overall.

Comment: That might be device specific. Did you contact the developer? Any logs (logcat) captured and sent along?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed this application called [Silence](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.epsilonlabs.silence.ads). It turns on and off settings based on a schedule.

That is EXACTLY what you asked for but like the others I suspect your issue is a run-away app using too much WiFi

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Norton apps may work, something like the Norton Task Manager. They have useful functions inside their apps.

Or, just search for "wifi disabler" in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Sentry](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dimet.sentry). It also has a paid version.

> Tired of accidentally leaving your WiFi running all day and wearing
>   down your device's battery? Tired of being home for hours and
>   forgetting to turn on your WiFi? Sentry can help!
>
> Sentry is a fully automated WiFi manager that only requires a simple
>   configuration to start. It packs many features into a simple-to-use
>   application so you don't have to waste any time on setup.
>
> Sentry operates by cycling your WiFi. If it gets a connection or was
>   already turned-on and connected, it remains on, otherwise, it turns
>   the WiFi off to save battery.
>
> Even if Sentry is activated you can still manually connect to WiFi or
>   turn your WiFi without interrupting.
>
> Sentry can be configured to run in any or all of three ways.
>
> First, Sentry can be configured to run on a polling interval, e.g. 30
>   minutes, and check the WiFi status periodically.
>
> Second, Sentry can set to check WiFi status every time the screen is
>   unlocked.**
>
> Last, Sentry can be set to run every time the phone boots up. Used in
>   conjunction with the other two functions, this can either be used to
>   make sure Sentry is always running or to simply check for WiFi every
>   time the phone reboots.
>
> Does Sentry running in the background use up my battery life? Nope!
>   Not one bit! Sentry is actually only ever truly running when it's
>   cycling the WiFi, which depending on the timeout you set, shouldn't be
>   for much more than a minute, so no, it shouldn't negatively affect
>   your battery life.

Comment: "Sentry operates by cycling your WiFi. If it gets a connection or was already turned-on and connected, **it remains on**, otherwise, it turns the WiFi off to save battery." This is exactly what I said I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest battery saving things you could do is to disable WiFi only when the screen is locked such as the device being in your pocket. I'm sure there are *many* ways of going about this, but this is the easiest and most reliable method that I know of.

With this you should be able to save a *lot* of battery!

If you just follow the instructions I've provided below, you should have satisfying results in just a few minutes!

---

1. Download **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** from the **Play Store.**
2. Open **Tasker** and click the `+` button. Now click **Event** → **Display** → **Display Off.**
3. Click the **gear** (back button) in the **top left corner.** A pop up menu will appear. Select **New Task** and name it `Display Off`.
4. Tap `+` → **Net** → **WiFi** and make sure the box that says **Set** is set to `Off`.
5. Click the gear (back) twice so that you end up on the **Profiles** screen.
6. Now click `+` again, then **Event** → **Display** → **Display On.**
7. Tap the gear (back) and then select **New Task**. Name it something along the lines of `Display On`.
8. Click `+` → **Net** → **WiFi** and change **Set** to `On`. Now exit back to the **Profiles** tab. You should now have both **Display Off** and **Display On.**
9. In the **Profiles** tab to the right of your conditions, there are **On/ Off** toggles. Turn both of these to <kbd>Off</kbd> and then back to <kbd>On</kbd>.
10. Simply exit out of **Tasker** and you're done!

---

Good luck and I hope this helps you!