# GPS Battery Drain -- LocationManagerService

Tags: battery-life, gps, 4.2-jelly-bean

EDIT 3: Someone pointed me in the right direction on another forum.  There was a bug with HD Widgets that rolled out yesterday. [HD Widgets Bug](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101580561852699031263/posts/hB8bngvLKy7)

As of yesterday I am getting a 35%/hour battery drain.  I have not installed any new apps that would have caused this, this literally came out of nowhere.  I noticed my phone was getting extremely warm in my pocket, pulled it out and say my battery was almost completely discharged and went in to look at what caused the battery to drain so fast.  Top app on the stock Android battery usage settings was Flixter.  I thought maybe something was wrong with the app, FC'd it and put my phone away.  This morning I took my phone off the charger (100%) put it in my pocket on my way to work and again my pocket got nice and warm.  Pulled it out and saw that I was already at 81% battery after about 40 minutes of driving.  Again I pulled up the battery settings and saw Maps was the number one culprit this time.

If I use an app that needs GPS it works fine, can lock on to location quickly, etc, but I am getting a huge battery drain all the time.  Using Better Battery Stats under partial wakelocks my top two drainers are "NLP PendingIntent client in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox" (Maps) and "LocationManagerService".

Anyone have any idea what I could try?  Been off the charger for an hour and already at 60%.

EDIT: I have rebooted the phone several times.

EDIT2: Just realized that when my phone is connected to WiFi the drain is much less than on network data.  Not sure if it's related, or just the extra battery required to constantly do a location fix over network data.  Just more information, if it helps.

Comment: Simply reboot the device. I've had that on multiple devices already, a reboot always cured this. What's causing this most likely is some other app having an unresolved WAKE_LOCK ("UFO": the app might have crashed with the WakeLock unreleased) on that (e.g. requesting location updates in an interval of 0 secs), that's a know issue (see also: [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575), in the section "What if it is the Android System itself?" of my answer).

Comment: Should have mentioned in the OP that I have rebooted several times.  Thanks, will add to OP.

Comment: Ouch -- that crossed with my answer, which now no longer seems to fit... In this case, all I can offer is a temporary work-around: If your device is running Android 4.0 or higher, try if disabling the Maps app solves it (*Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*, scroll to "Maps", tap the entry, tap the "Disable" button). When you need *Maps* again, you can always enable it. You could also try clearing Cache (and optionally also data) from the *Maps* app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there was a rogue update from HD Widgets that caused this: [HD Widgets Bug](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101580561852699031263/posts/hB8bngvLKy7) I have emailed the developer and hopefully they can update soon.  This was insane how debilitating this was to my phone.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer:

Simply reboot the device. I've had that on multiple devices already, a reboot always cured this.

### Explanation:

The real culprit is not the *LocationManagerService* itself, but the way how is dealt with it. In my answer to the question [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575) you find a section called *What if it is the Android System itself?*, which explains this to a degree (and offers a link to further information):

An app might have requested location updates with a frequency of 0 seconds, thus keeping the device busy. Instead of requesting a "partial wakelock" (with an appropriate auto-timeout), it might have requested a permanent one (which it needs to release explicitly). If now this app crashed, the wakelock gets orphaned, the request for location updates remains, and nothing (but a reboot) can solve this.

This is just a raw description and probably not 100% technically perfect -- but I tried to put it into "laymen's words" to make it easier to understand. If somebody wants to put the details into "technically perfect terms", feel free to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to look under Google play to make sure your apps are not set to automatically update. I had a friend that did this for every app on their phone and would suck the battery life like crazy BC especially if the service wasn't great was constantly trying to update the apps.