# Sudden drop in battery life

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I used to get average good battery life, i.e. for about 2 days without re-charging, since yesterday my Samsung S2 battery life has become terrible, I haven't installed any new applications.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Settings** - **Battery** and take a look at the usage. You should see if there are any apps using an unexpected percentage of battery life. I've also seen location based apps drain my battery, but that's not saying that's what's causing your issues though.

Comment: That's in fact the first place to look for. I have this from time to time on some devices -- until now, always Google Maps was the culprit. And the solution was a simple reboot -- until Maps did it again a few weeks later... As that always had to do with WakeLocks, a look into [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/16575) might prove helpful, too.