# Tablet will not sleep

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, standby

My Xperia tablet Z is set to sleep after 30 seconds of inactivity. However starting yesterday it no longer goes to sleep at all and the battery just goes flat. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Check this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks Maybe you have apps keeping your tablet awake