# GTalk_ASYNC_CONN wakelock detailed report. Keeps draining batteries

Tags: google-apps, google, wakelock

It's been a month since I've tried dealing with this wakelock. I've read a lot of articles, including [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks). A week ago I was also dealing with NlpWakelockCollector, which sometimes gets stucked draining my battery and sometimes not.

This time the problem is GTalk_ASYNC_CONN. I really don't know what's the problem with Google. It's frustrating.
Here it is what I did.

1. Full Charge 100%. Didn't touch it for about ~2 hours.
2. Set the alarm clock and went to sleep at about 6am.
3. Woke up at 12.50pm and the first I did was to save the LogCat's log and check Wakelock Detector and GSam Battery Monitor apps. Screenshots here,

[image: Wakelock Detector] [image: GSam Battery Monitor]

and this is my log from Logcat: http://tny.cz/8122229f

PS. I had uninstalled Hangouts and reinstalled it replacing Google Talk again, thereupon I logged out from Hangouts. This was two days ago.