# What is exynos5-fb.1 wakelock?

Tags: wakelock

Samsung Galaxy S4 running stock Android 4.3. This wakelock is mysterious. What is it? It's taking up a big chunk of my Awake time. How do I stop it? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks)

Comment: Seems like it's the frame buffer kernel driver of the Exynos chip used in Galaxy S4 (which basically means you can't do anything about it), but it's just a hunch, maybe someone can supply better information.

Answer (score 1):

It is You Tube.  Even after turning my tablet off, while charging, or not, You Tube starts running, on it's on, and wont stop until I force stop it.   Everyday when I seen battery drain or battery not charged after hours of charge time the first thing I do is check task manager and there it is, You Tube running.

Comment: Credible sources to back your claim would be appreciated