# Android 4.3 autoscreen turn on

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2, bugs, power-on

This issue I noticed,once i updated my android to 4.3.
The issue is after every **1 min** the lock screen automatically turns on.
There was no problem before.
Please help,i dont want to degrade to 4.1 again.

Device-Samsung Galaxy Note 2.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for us to help you. From what I've seen of similar issues in the past, there's probably some app that needs to have the screen on in order to function. What do you have that updates every minute? You might need to start taking apps off and using a process of elimination to find the culprit.

Comment: Full ack to Al's comment, and let me add something: A "full wakelock" does such things (turning the screen on to make sure the device is fully awake). To find the app requesting this, a useful resource thus might be [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/16575)

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, on the exact same device.

Comment: I don't have a Galaxy Note 2, but I would recommend just turning on Debug mode and running adb logcat and hoping that you can see the culprit make an announcement when it happens.

Comment: Using WakeLock detector from [the wakelock thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks), the only apps that seem to trigger a screen wakelock are the default messaging app and the package installer. I've turned both of these off, and the screen still keeps turning on.

Comment: Using Tasker?  (or Locale, Llama, etc)  Tasker has a compatibility setting that turns the screen on when checking certain conditions.

Comment: @smhmic, nope, I am not using Tasker or those other apps :(

Comment: @stringo0 Have you tried turning Sync off? Maybe there is a sync adapter that is misbehaving.

Comment: @Andris, yes I have. I'm starting to think it could be a hardware issue with mine.

Answer (score 4):

I also recently upgraded my Note2 from 4.1 to 4.3 and was having the same problem. I installed the Wakelock Detector by UzumApps and found that the Noom Walk pedometer app was waking the screen. I uninstalled the Noom Walk app and the screen no longer wakes. The Noom developers have posted a test APK which can be found here: http://noom.uservoice.com/forums/207934-feature-requests-noom-walk-/suggestions/4147991-fix-noom-walk-on-the-samsung-galaxy-note-ii
I have not tried it yet. I may post more later if I try installing it.

Comment: That seemed to be it for me! The Wakelock detector didn't show the Walk app waking the screen, but uninstalling it has fixed it! No wake ups any more! Yay! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Android has different lock options - PIN, pattern, or facial recognition,.. .
Change current lock option to other and see if issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MAkS! It didn't seem to work. I changed it and it still turns on every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 'Daydream' turned on. Settings->Display->Daydream on Android 4.4. I was playing with my Nexus 7 and noticed that it would bring up the clock when I left it alone so it could be that. I must have turned it on when I was playing around with new features as it was introduced in Android 4.2.