# Excessive data and battery usage with Samsung S7 on Android 6.0.1

Tags: samsung, battery

Recently I bought a *Samsung Galaxy S7.* I had an *S6 Edge,* and no problems with Android OS data usage/battery drain.

The big problem is, I don't know why, but Android OS is eating my mobile data and wi-fi data, and my battery too!!!

I have the same apps of my S6 edge on the S7, I'm reading all topics on the internet, but no success. Please see the screenshots! Thanks!

I restricted almost everything from backgroung, installed Doze, installed Greenify, I'm trying everything, but this ANDROID OS keeps eating everything!

Sorry about my english, I'm from another country.

[image: BATTERY DRAIN] [image: MOBILE DATA USAGE]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Please ignore the *Google Play Store* usage in the second screenshot (it is already set to auto-update on WiFi only; that usage was done on purpose one day that my Wi-Fi was offline, and I wanted to test my 4G). The big problem is my battery drain about android OS and data usage. Play Store is fine, no more usage.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I've integrated that with your question. Next step: Wakelocks. One of the usual suspects here are the Location Services which (e.g. when some app excessively uses them) may hide behind "Android OS". For a guide, please check [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/16575) Especially look at the section "What if it is the Android System itself" in [my answer there](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34972/16575).

Comment: Hello Izzy, I'll take a look. Thanks!! Will answer to you later.

Comment: Hi Izzy, I read everything, and it's very interesting and easy to understand!! Thanks for that. But the problem is, both apps needs "root", I can't figure out WakeLocks, because both apps needs "root" :( . I'll just keep trying other options! I even paid for BetterBatteryStats, but no use, hehehe.... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh. Maybe take a look at [Wakelock detection without root](http://forums.androidcentral.com/moto-x-2013/541427-wakelock-detection-without-root.html) at AndroidCentral then? Not tested it myself, but surely worth a try. Let me know the results, I might need to update that other post then :)

Comment: Hello Izzy, I downloaded the 2 files to try using the PC, but no success, I'm not an expert with that, but I tried, and I couldn't find a place that explains how to do that step by step on the PC. So, I think it has no solution for me. One thing that I did and got a little better, was to exit SnapChat, and turn location services just to WiFi and MobileData, and GPS OFF. It improved a little, but I still have the problem.

Comment: OK, another suggestion to "work on the symptoms" then – as your comment suggests we're on the right track with location stuff. Try turning location off altogether to see if we really are (one day you might live without for the big goal, right? ;) If that gives a Whoa! switch it back on, but forbid all apps accessing it. Then allow it app-by-app until the culprit is identified. Might be a shot into the blue, but nothing to lose here :)

Comment: Izzy, well, I think I'm getting there. I disabled only the GPS and let WiFi and data usage ON for location. Also I didn't log in to SnapChat. I fully charged my S7 yesterday, and didn't leave my home, my battery is on 72% and I've been on battery for 17h!!!! That's a big improvement. I'm using instagram, whatsapp, google, internet, emails, and I have 12 hours left! So I think it's something related to snapchat or GPS location. Maybe not? I disabled right now Google Now, and I'll check if my battery goes down fast if I move from my home to another place. Maybe it's google now? Well.. lets see.

Comment: Also I forgot to say, I'm using Doze App, and it was not helping these days. It's still ON, but only got better after I turned off GPS location and exited SnapChat. BUT the Android OS is still consuming a little power and a little data usage.

Comment: "a little" is OK (network location needs that, sending SSIDs/CellIDs to the servers to get back coordinates). The context suggests a bug in Snapchat, which might "constantly request location data". But as you've switched two variables (Snapchat *and* GPS), it also might be something else. You might already have narrowed it down; next maybe try leaving Snapchat off and re-enable GPS – and then the other way around?

Comment: Okay, enabled full GPS now. Snapchat OFF, Google Now OFF. Let's see.

Comment: Well, and again you've introduced an additional variable. Only change one thing a time, makes evaluating results much easier. As you've done now, if things "look good", that just means either Snapchat or Google Now make too much use of GPS. Hadd you left GN as it was, you'd have a much clearer result and could tell "Snapchat using too much GPS" in the same case (or that that's not the case otherwise). Happy playing ;)

Comment: Hi Izzy, I fully charged my cellphone at night. I let gps ON and snapchat ON, but I didn't touch the S7, and it stayed for 6 hours with the screen off. Battery went from 100% to 96% in these 6 hours, thats good I think. I've been paying attention to one thing. After these 6 hours, I went to battery status, and it didn't show the Android OS battery usage. Android OS battery usage only started to consume my battery when my screen is ON and when I'm using my S7. When I turn off screen, it stops to consume power. I'm monitoring by power usage in mAh.

Comment: I'm a little lost. I didn't left my home, so I didn't "change location". I think the big problem is Google Now that everytime requests my position. Argh. Because Snapchat was ON all night and GPS ON all night, and just 4% of battery drain in 6 hours. Screen OFF. I think I'll get a better result tomorrow.

Comment: You can try wakelock detector version which doesn't require root.  See [answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/146399/131553) also greenify latest stable version has *aggressive doze* which kicks in much faster than regular doze. Further, beta version allows you to let the doze continue when when in motion!  I am using this combo effectively