# How to make Snapchat use less battery/network?

Tags: battery-life, snapchat

I barely use [Snapchat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapchat), less than 10 text snaps per day, only one or two 300KB pictures, and I almost never watch nor send videos. I never use the rightmost activity (branded content).

Despite this very limited usage, Snapchat consistently wastes a LOT of battery:

[image: Snapchat battery usage]

Network usage is also way over what it should be. Data usage alone is not high enough to explain the huge battery drain though.

Just staying on a conversation screen (zero activity) drains more power than the outlet can provide. You read this correctly: Even with the phone plugged into the wall, if Snapchat is open the battery level decreases and eventually the phone has to shut down, this happened to me yesterday with a Nexus 5.

Is there anything I can do to prevent Snapchat from using that much power?

- Use a firewall to block useless branded content download?
- Remove some permissions? (phone is rooted)

I only need conversation with friends, which means I don't mind losing branded content, sponsored stories, etc. I don't care much about my friend's profiles/stories either.

Note: That's despite having enabled `Settings > Manage > Travel Mode` already:

[image: Snapchat Travel Mode]

Comment: I don't use Snapchat- maybe these [settings](http://www.techinsider.io/keep-snapchat-from-draining-battery-life-2016-5#) help?

Comment: @beeshyams: That URL has two tips: the first I had already enabled, the second is for iPhone. Thanks though!

Comment: Suggest install [Wakelock detector as explained here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/131553) as first step- second step could be to limit those wakelocks coming from snapchat without breaking functionality using Amplify (requires Xposed )