# What is preventing my phone from staying locked?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lock-screens, nexus-5

Normally, when I press the power button on my phone, the screen turns off and when I press it again, I'm presented with the lock screen.  (I don't have a password or pattern, so it's just the "Swipe up to unlock" screen.)

In the last month or so, my phone has started exhibiting the symptom that I press the power button and the screen turns off, but when I press the power button again, it's *not* at the lock screen, but whatever the front application happens to be.  Sometimes I'll note that about 20 seconds after I press the power button to lock the screen, the phone will emit another sound from the speakers that sounds a lot like the "I've just locked" click.

This doesn't happen all of the time.  At a guess, I'd say that about a third of the times that I wake from a black screen, I get no lock screen.  Also, I'm not sure if pressing the power button to lock vs. a timeout makes any difference.

It seems to me that there must be some application that's keeping the phone from locking, but I think I've uninstalled all the applications that I installed shortly before this started happening.  I'm guessing that it's an application that had been recently updated, but I don't know how to track that down.

I don't really want to uninstall apps one-by-one, as I can't reproduce the problem.  It never happens when I want it to.

Does anyone have any ideas how to track down this problem?

This is on a Nexus 5 running 6.0.1, rooted.  (I never do anything with root, though, and it's preventing me from upgrading, so I should really undo it.)

Comment: There's a setting is Settings - Security - Screen Lock settings - "Automatically lock" is a timer, and "Power button instantly locks" is on/off, are either of those set?

Comment: @RMarkwald: I don't see those settings.  The only screen lock settings I see are Screen Lock (None, ***Swipe***, Pattern, PIN, Password), Lock Screen Message (None), and Smart Lock (disabled).

Comment: Is there a gear icon or anything on Swipe to adjust its settings at all?

Comment: @RMarkwald: Nope. No icon; long press just selects; three dots icon on that screen is just "Help & feedback".  Remember that it works as I expect about two-thirds of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Since you suspect this to be app related, install [wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) which should help you identify the wakelocks that are *holding* the screen awake. Read the *Screen Wakelock* section

Once the culprit is identified, Googling for that would lead you to the app, if the app name is not evident ( You may need to monitor over a few hours repeatedly, since the behaviour reported is not consistent)

*Edit:* Remember to monitor when the phone is not being used. Charging the phone to a fixed percentage like 90% before retiring for bed would be ideal monitoring time

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a shot. My concern is that I've never seen this *prevent* the screen from locking; it seems to force it to unlock after it's been locked. Hopefully my concern is unfounded.

Comment: That is exactly what an errant Wakelock does. It can affect the screen or CPU . See this to know better http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/131553

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I'll post positive results when I have them or negative results in a few days.

Comment: All the best. Please see the edit

Comment: Turns out that Wakelock Detector doesn't record information while the phone is charging.  Now that I know, I'll leave it off the charger tonight.

Comment: It's been longer than a few days because ever since I installed Wakelock Detector my phone has been acting weird.  One time the pulldown settings text changed to something bizarre that I don't remember (instead of the date and time). Wireless settings and such kept changing themselves. Bluetooth is now disabled every time I reboot. It just rebooted itself for no apparent reason. One thing it hasn't done is fail to lock. (to be continued)

Comment: The first few days WLD showed me that [Draw!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.thewongandonly.QuickDraw) had performed a wakelock. I can't imagine why a drawing app, especially one I hadn't been using, would do that, so I uninstalled it. I then checked the reviews to see if anyone else had reported anything, but then I noticed it had just been updated.  So I don't know if that had anything to do with it or not.  I'm going to uninstall WLD now and see if I'm still unlock free.

Comment: It could just be a poorly developed app or a bug in the app. Uninstalling WLD will not make a difference as it only monitors wakelocks . Anyway, hope your problem gets resolved