# Screen Timeout not Working

Tags: screen-timeout

My Pixel 2 running stock android 10 seems to not respect the screen timeout setting. I have it set to ten minutes, and sometimes after putting the phone down with the screen on when it is fully charged and picking it up a few hours later it would be dead.

Comment: Have you at least checked the device after 15 minutes? A not working screen timeout is just one potential reason. Therefore you should check if it is really the reason. BTW: The Pixel2 has an AMOLED display, setting a screen timeout to 10 minutes has a high risk that you will face the OLED burn-in effect very soon.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I have checked the phone between leaving it on and it dying, I've had the phone on and taken a 30 minute nap and it was still on when I got back to it. Also, does that mean that 10 minutes is too high for a screen timeout?

Comment: Probably some aggressive wakelocks, perhaps you can refer to this question: [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/44325)